# How to know if you are "tough enough" to study Algebraic Topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question, advice

I am graduating with a BA this summer and I am very interested in topology. I admit it, I never went that deep into topology and all I know is about point-set topology (metric spaces etc.) but from personal readings, I love the style of proofs in topology and I have a general idea about how things go there, so I think I can go through Munkres' which will virtually pave the way for me to start studying algebraic topology. I have a solid grasp of abstract algebra, differential geometry and basically everything a typical undergrad should have covered and I think that I am ready to take on something challenging.

However, I heard from many grad students that algebraic topology is very difficult in comparison to other areas and that I should have known much more before now to start with serious stuff. So I am bit scared of taking on something which might later turn out to be out of my reach.

To frame my question well: is algebraic topology that difficult compared to other areas of research in which one might pursue their graduate studies? How much should you know and how mathematically powerful should you be in order to successfully obtain a PhD in algebraic topology in a reasonable time?

Comment: If you are worried you could do Wildberger's Algebraic Topology first.

Comment: Feh. All math is difficult, if you're doing it right. If you like topology and algebra, I don't see why you shouldn't do what you want -- it beats doing something you sorta like because somebody else said it's easier. Obviously there are limitations to my philosophy, but I'm fairly sure an adviser would not let you work on algebraic topology if they did not think you were capable (i.e., it's ultimately *their* opinion that matters).

Comment: Going through Munkries carefully is worthwhile even if you don't end up doing algebraic topology research.  So this is a good way to learn something useful and keep your mental edge, while waiting to start your grad studies.

Comment: Read some book and take your own opinion about the matter. There is a lot of differences between people.

Comment: P.S. I loved the construction at the end of chapter 1, before even getting into topology, of a well-ordered uncountable set.  It is buried in the exercises, and I found the gem while working all the exercises years after I had originally taken the course.

Comment: When I was in grad school, I always found people who said "I'm studying $X$, it's so much more difficult than $Y$" to be insufferable complainers and often weak students. Study what you are interested in and have fun.

Answer (score 12):

Algebraic topology, by it's very nature,is not an easy subject because it's really an uneven mixture of algebra and topology unlike any other subject you've seen before.However,**how** difficult it can be  to me depends on how you present algebraic topology and the chosen level of abstraction.

If you want to use a high-tech and fully general approach, where everything is presented via diagram chases and category theory a la Peter May or Tammo Tom Dieck's texts-then yes,the subject can be brutal even for a well prepared student. In this case, the subject really resembles an algebra course a lot more then what you're used to in a topology or geometry course.For this kind of course,a very strong background in algebra with category theory is more important then any topology or geometry background.

However, if your professor prefers a more classical,geometric approach like Allen Hatcher's book or an approach via differential forms on manifolds such as in Bott/Tu's classic text or Bredon's book, then the ability to visualize and connect to constructions in locally Euclidean spaces becomes much more important.In this case,your background in differential geometry is going to come in quite handy.

Again, it'll really depend on your professor's background and what approach he/she prefers.A book I'd suggest you look at as a warmup to a serious algebraic topology course is John M. Lee's *An Introduction To Topological Manifolds*. It covers all the prerequisites needed for a serious algebraic topology course-the basics of point set topology, homotopy theory,commutative diagrams and category theory and the classification of compact surfaces-in a completely modern and very geometric way. I suspect you'll find a serious algebraic topology course a lot easier if you work your way through this book first.